# Push elements into array using eventlistener("click" , function(array))

Tags: javascript, arrays, event-listener

I have attached an event listener to a button and for the function in the function for the event listener , I am trying to pass an array that I wish to update every time the button is clicked. Is this possible? If so what am I doing wrong because I am not sure how to see if array1 is being updated. Thanks in advance.

```
var array1 = new Array();
buttons.addEventListener("click", update(array1));
function update(array){
  array.push("*");
  console.log(array);
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the HTML code also?

Comment: Also, we can't see the buttons, so please get some more info in

Comment: And you should write the real scenario. I could not understand why you do not use `<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>` and what would like to see printing an array to the console.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the reference of the function and not execute it with `()`

```
buttons.addEventListeners("click", update);
```

In your case you want to pass arguments aswell, so you need to `.bind()` it:

```
buttons.addEventListeners("click", update.bind(null, array1));
```

The first argument is the `this` argument. If you want to change the context of `this`. The other arguments are the arguments that you want to pass

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote it the function is immediately called and not on click event

```
buttons.addEventListener("click", update(array1));
```

you can use the arrow function syntax , that way your update function will be called correctly on click event

```
buttons.addEventListener("click", ()=>update(array1));
```